# How do I see the definition of a data type in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

I have a data type("my_schema.my_data_type"), and I want to see the definition, because some columns use this data type.

I know that it's likely a character type, and accepts only a few values. Is there a way like `\d+ table_name`, or a function that I can call on this data type to see more about it?

Comment: `\dT+`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Comment: That was it, thanks! I checked the options with `\?` a few times, but was blind enough not to see it.